# insert a character into a list in python

Tags: python, list, replace

i have this list in which after every space i need to insert ; so that i will be able to separate the list later in my code according to my requirements.I have tried split() and join methods but found out that works only on strings so how do i insert ; instead of space

```
 ['48998.tyrone-cluster       gic1_nwgs        mbupi           18:45:44 R qp32           \n', 
'48999.tyrone-cluster       gic2_nwgs        mbupi                  0 Q batch          \n',  
'49005.tyrone-cluster       ...01R-1849-01_2 mcbkss          00:44:23 R qp32           \n',
'49032.tyrone-cluster       gaussian_top.sh  chemraja               0 Q qp32           \n', 
'49047.tyrone-cluster       jet_egrid        asevelt         312:33:0 R qp128          \n']
```

output must be like this

```
['48998.tyrone-cluster;gic1_nwgs;mbupi;18:45:44;R;qp32', 
'48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch',  
'49005.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1849-01_2;mcbkss;00:44:23;R;qp32',
'49032.tyrone-cluster;gaussian_top.sh;chemraja;0;Q;qp32', 
'49047.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;312:33:0;R;qp128']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` on whitespace then  rejoin using `;`:

```
l[:] = [";".join(line.split())for line in l]
print(l)

['48998.tyrone-cluster;gic1_nwgs;mbupi;18:45:44;R;qp32', '48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch', '49005.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1849-01_2;mcbkss;00:44:23;R;qp32', '49032.tyrone-cluster;gaussian_top.sh;chemraja;0;Q;qp32', '49047.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;312:33:0;R;qp128']
```

Or use `enumerate` and a for loop:

```
for ind, line in enumerate(l):
    l[ind] = ";".join(line.split())
print(l)
```

Both methods will update the original list.

Answer (score 2):

Split with `.split()` on whitespace, and join using the `';'` as the delimiter:

```
>>> transformed = [ ';'.join(item.split()) for item in original ]
>>> pprint(transformed)
['48998.tyrone-cluster;gic1_nwgs;mbupi;18:45:44;R;qp32',
 '48999.tyrone-cluster;gic2_nwgs;mbupi;0;Q;batch',
 '49005.tyrone-cluster;...01R-1849-01_2;mcbkss;00:44:23;R;qp32',
 '49032.tyrone-cluster;gaussian_top.sh;chemraja;0;Q;qp32',
 '49047.tyrone-cluster;jet_egrid;asevelt;312:33:0;R;qp128']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import re
out_list = []
for word in in_list:
  out_list.append(re.sub(' +',' ',word).replace(' \n','').replace(' ',';'))
print "Result",out_list
```